# Números romanos

Tags: javascript

tengo por la mitad este código por la mitad para convertir números arábicos a romanos, el problema que tengo es que no encuentro la manera para que los números mayores que 5 sean los correspondientes a su contraparte romana

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
  let oneRoman = "I"
  let fiveRoman = "V"
  let tenRoman = "X"
  let fifRoman = "L"
  let hunRoman = "C"
  let fifhunRoman = "D"
  let millionRoman = "M" 
  let totalRoman = ""
  
  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    if(num >= 1 && num <=3){
      totalRoman += oneRoman;
    }else if(num ===4){
      totalRoman = oneRoman + fiveRoman
    }else if(num ===5){
      totalRoman = fiveRoman
    }else if(num >= 6 && num <= 8){
      fiveRoman += oneRoman
      totalRoman = fiveRoman
    }
  }
  return totalRoman
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuáles son los posibles valores de `num`?

Comment: ejemplo 9:  residuo de división > 1 entonces agregas  V y restas 5 al numero y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Esta orriblemente implementada esa logica de divicion ... XD

Answer (score 0):

Esto a mi me funciona, espero que te sirva:

```js
function romanize (num) { 
 if (isNaN(num))
   return NaN; 
  var digits = String(+num).split(""), 
      key = ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM", "","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC", "","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"], 
      roman = "",
      i = 3; 
  while (i--) 
    roman = (key[+digits.pop() + (i * 10)] || "") + roman; 
  return Array(+digits.join("") + 1).join("M") + roman; 
}

console.log(romanize(1756));
console.log(romanize(3551));
```